# cakephp find 'first' not pulling data

Tags: cakephp-2.0, cakephp-model

I have a link that calls:

```
<a href="/coupons/print_coupon/<?php echo $coupon['id']; } ?>" id="print"><span style="margin-left:24px;">Print</span></a>
```

It plugs in the correct id, and my route sends it to the correct view file.  I have a debug command to show the entire array for the print page, but I'm getting an empty array.  Here is my controller code:

```
<?php 
class CouponsController extends AppController {
    public $name='Coupons';
    public $uses=array('User', 'Coupon', 'Restaurant');
    public $layout='pagelayout';


    public function print_coupon($name=null) {
      $this->set('title', 'Print your coupon');
      $f=$this->Coupon->find('first', array('conditions'=>array('Coupon.id'=>$this->params['id'])));
      $this->set('name', $f);
    }
```

}
?>

Here is my Coupon Model:

```
<?php
class Coupon extends AppModel {
    public $name='Coupon';
    var $belongsTo=array(
    'Restaurant'=>array (
        'className'=>'Restaurant',
        'foreignKey'=>'restaurant_id'
        )
    );
}
```

?>

and here is my Restaurant Model:

```
<?php

class Restaurant extends AppModel {
public $name='Restaurant';
var $hasMany=array(
    'Coupon'=>array(
        'className'=>'Coupon',
        'foreignKey'=>'restaurant_id'
        )
);
var $belongsTo=array(
'User'=>array(
'className'=>'User',
'foreignKey'=>'user'
)
);

}


?>
```

I have tried variations using

```
 <a href="/coupons/print_coupon/<?php echo $res['Restaurant']['coupon']; } ?>" id="print"><span style="margin-left:24px;">Print</span></a>
```

along with in my controller:

```
public function print_coupon($name=null) {
      $this->set('title', 'Print your coupon');
      $f=$this->Coupon->find('first', array('conditions'=>array('Coupon.id'=>$this->params['id'])));
      $this->set('name', $f);
    }
```

as well as a few others, and whenever I debug($name) I get an empty array.  I have had no problems associating Coupon with my other models for other tasks yet, but i think something may be wrong with my Restaurant Model.

For reference, I have these are equal to each other:
   Restaurants.coupon = Coupon.id
   Coupon.restaurant_id=Restaurant.id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first anchor code you posted has a curly brace that shouldn't be there. When you use this:

```
<a href="/coupons/print_coupon/<?php echo $coupon['id']; ?>" id="print"><span style="margin-left:24px;">Print</span></a>
```

It should yield some url that's like this:

```
/coupons/print_coupon/75
```

Then in your CouponsController that 75 turns into the `$name` in your print_coupon parameters (with default routing settings), I recommend changing that to `$coupon_id`, so your function should look like this:

```
public function print_coupon($coupon_id) {
  $this->set('title', 'Print your coupon');
  $f=$this->Coupon->find('first', array('conditions'=>array('Coupon.id'=>$coupon_id)));
  $this->set('name', $f);
}
```

Now `$name` should be accessible in your view. With this code above, `$name` won't exist within the controller.

I don't think `$this->params` exists in Cake 2.*. `debug($this->request->params);` You can get the params from there in the controller, though.

Comment: That worked.  I had the curly brace in the code as the link was part of a foreach loop (so left that unchanged), and plugged in $coupon_id.  $this->params was working for me in another controller in this app, so I guess it is still working even if deprecated.  Could you explain to me why my code wouldn't work?  It doesn't seem very different from your approach;  I am still quite the noob at logic, so any insights you can give me are greatly appreciated.

Comment: It was because of this line: `$f=$this->Coupon->find('first', array('conditions'=>array('Coupon.id'=>$this->params['id'])));`. The `75` from my example is a `'pass'` variable. You can access it like in my example (`$coupon_id`) or like this: `$f=$this->Coupon->find('first', array('conditions'=>array('Coupon.id'=>$this->params['pass'][0])));`. `$this->params['id']` will never exist, so no results will ever be found (unless you had a coupon with a null id). `$this->params` is an array, so it's just a matter of getting the right index of what you need. `$this->params['pass']` is an indexed array.